# How the pass HTML element, from one method to other in prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, es6-class

How to pass the result from the method playerElementChoice() to startGame()

```
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.options = document.querySelectorAll('.options');
         this.options.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('click', this.playerElementChoice);
        });


    document.querySelector('button.start').addEventListener('click', this.startGame.bind(this));

}

playerElementChoice() {
    const name = this.firstElementChild.className;
    return name;
}

startGame() {
    console.log(this.playerElementChoice());
}
```

}

When trying to call the method playerElementChoice ()in method startGame() I get error:
Cannot read property 'className' of undefined at Game.playerElementChoice (Game.js:17) at Game.startGame (Game.js:28).

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `playerElementChoice` requires a `this` context of an element with a child, but in `console.log(this.playerElementChoice());`, you're invoking it with the context of the Game instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to select the single option in a list, and log the selected li className value, you must change your code adding some binding:

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.options = Array.from(document.getElementById('options').children);
    this.startButton = document.querySelector('button.start');
    this.name = '';
    this.playerElementChoice = this.playerElementChoice.bind(this);
    this.startGame = this.startGame.bind(this)
  }
  
  init() {
    this.options.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', this.playerElementChoice)
    });
   this.startButton.addEventListener('click', this.startGame);
  }

  playerElementChoice(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.name = e.target.className;
}

  startGame() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

let game = new Game()
game.init()
```

```html
<button class="start">start</button>
<ul id="options">
  <li class="option1" name="one">1</li>
  <li class="option2" name="two">2</li>
  <li class="option3" name="three">3</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps